# Problems with PDF fonts generated with ggsave under windows when linking in Illustrator

Tags: pdf, ggplot2, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I run into problems with embedded (or not embedded?) fonts in PDFs of ggplots created with ggsave and linked into illustrator files, for some reason on windows only.

For my workflow I link plots into illustrator where I create figures with several plots. I don't embed the plots because in case something changes in R the plots are automatically updated when Illustrator is reopened.
So the problem is that when trying to save such files I always get an error message that saving is not possible because the Font "^1" could not be embedded. I can save the illustrator files when I disable PDF compatibility but cannot save them as PDF, which is what I need.

I don't get this problem if I use `ggsave(plot, device=cairo_pdf)`, but with `cairo_pdf`I run into other problems (e.g. with `geom_rangeframe`).
In previous posts I read about an issue with the dingbats or AdobePiStd font, but using `ggsave(plot, useDingpats=F)` does not solve it. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your update seem to be an answer to your question. You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then mark it correct after a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I could solve the problem with the `embedFonts` function. The the problem seems to be that the fonts are not embedded by default. I wrote a small function to use instead of ggsave to automatically embed the fonts into the same PDF file:

```
ggsave_embed<-function(fileN, ...){
ggsave(fileN, ...)
embedFonts(file=fileN, outfile = fileN)
}
# example usage:
ggsave_embed("myfile.pdf", myPlot)
```